# Tensorflow Model parallelism error

Tags: tensorflow

I actually want to implement model parallelism automatically in the tensorflow.

I little bit correct the code of tensorflow in the placement code(simple_placer.cc) in version 1.3. However the placement was work in case of MNIST, but it has an error on inception.

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Trying to access resource located in device /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/cpu:0 from device /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0
```

I want to get some advice about this error such as when the error comes up or what condition makes this errors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error typically happens when some operation attempts to read one of its inputs, but that input happens to reside on another device. Typically, when tensorflow places operations on different devices, it inserts send/recv nodes into the execution graph to exchange tensors between these devices. You changes might have broken some of that logic.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. There could be the case which input node is in machine 1(M1), and data is separated in M1, M2, and etc. Then when input node access the data which is in M1 there is no error however, when input node access the data in M2 or other machines, the error which I mentioned will be occured, am I right?

Comment: Then is there any way to add recv/send node corresponding to input node in every machine which has input data?

Comment: There certainly is a way - that is handling of GPU and CPU (even on the same machine) works today. I don't know that code well enough to suggest anything concrete and my guess is that it is a pretty hard project. Also, that C++ code is not part of the public API and subject to change at any time. Even if you manage to get it working today, it can break tomorrow. I would suggest trying to work at higher-level in python.